# XML Parsing : Insert XML data into database : performance

Tags: xml, performance, parsing

Do you have an idea about the most performant way to parse XML into a database.

"fastest way".

read XML, do some checks, then  insert the result into a database.

Thanks.

Comment: The most performant way is to use an XML data store and not do any parsing. If that is not acceptable you need to tell us why.

Comment: @med_alpa: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Don't forget to read carefully all sections of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You will earn a badge and improve your Stackoverflow experience.

Answer (score 0):

**Main question is**

Do you want it to be done programatically or with an already made application?

**Programatically**

It depends on how the XML is written. If the tag/property names matches the database tables/columns then you can write it in a pretty easy way, if not, you'll need to map the xml tag/property names first to match the database structure.

For a proper answer, I'll need to know the current language you'll be writing it.

**Applications**

One example:
http://www.altova.com/databasespy/database-import-export.html

Comment: OK thanks, : I want it programatically. The language used is Java. The XML files matches the tables columns in almost of the cases. There are some countable tables where the xmls contains more fields than the table.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider:

1. Make sure you parse your XML using streaming API, such as SAX or StAX, not walk through using the DOM API.
2. Use a preparedstatement and batch your inserts in batches of let's say, 1000 inserts.

In Java, you could use [StaxMate](http://staxmate.codehaus.org/), which gives you a small layer above StAX. Then do the check and the insert in an inner loop:

Prepare your database insert statement outside the loop like:

```
    Connection conn = ...
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (?, ?,...)");
    static int i=0;
```

And in the inner loop:

```
ps.setInt(1, a); 
ps.setString(2, b);
...
ps.addBatch();
if(++i % 1000==0) ps.executeBatch()
```